# Getting a chart of Google Trends responsive

Tags: charts, google-trends, responsiveness

I'm wondering if it is possible to get the charts for Google Trends responsive with the current given code (by adding an 'unknown' parameters)

### Example

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//www.google.com/trends/embed.js?hl=en-US&q=hoest,+Bronchitis,+Bronchiolitis,+RSV&geo=BE&date=1/2011+49m&cmpt=q&tz&tz&content=1&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w=900&h=330"></script>
```

It is anyway not working when putting '100%' as width value.
But anyone aware of an extra parameter to change the unit you want to use (which is px by default)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try getting the screen width with javascript on page load, then dynamically create the embed code replacing the defined width parameter with the actual screen width.

```
<script>

//function which gets screen width
function getWidth() {
  if (self.innerHeight) {
    return self.innerWidth;
  }

  if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
    return document.documentElement.clientWidth;
  }

  if (document.body) {
    return document.body.clientWidth;
  }
}

    //define screen width variable. Subtract 15 pixels from width just to be on the safe side and reduce chance of getting a horizontal scroll bar
    var screenWidth = getWidth()-Number(15);

    //replace the following URL with your own. Be sure to keep the modified part of the string in tact where it replaces the width with screenWidth variable
    var embedCode = "//www.google.com.au/trends/embed.js?hl=en-US&q=mick+fanning,+wwe&geo=ZA&date=now+7-d&cmpt=q&tz=Etc/GMT-10&tz=Etc/GMT-10&content=1&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=5&w="+screenWidth+"&h=330";


//write this new code to browser. Split '<script'> tags to prevent browser errors when writing.
document.write('<scr'+'ipt type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"'+embedCode+'\"></scr'+'ipt>');

</script>
```

Note the width of the chart will not adjust if the browser window changes. (ie, user flips their phone sideways).

Answer (score 0):

If you click the menu on the top right of the trends graph there is an option to embed the graph in Desktop or Mobile views. Select Mobile and it will do the responsiveness for you and give you the code snippet.

[image: example of responsive embed code]